# Как отменить скрол при фокусировке на input поле в мобильном браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, мобильная-разработка

Если мы кликнем по полю, на него перейдет фокус. Проблема в том, что помимо фокуса произойдет прокрутка страницы к этому элементу. Можно ли как-то это поведение (скрол) исключить?

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос. Сделать это, по видимому, можно только так:

```
function stopScroll(e) {
    var t = e.target;
    if (t.tagName !== 'INPUT' || 
        t.type.toLowerCase() !== 'text') return;

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;

    t.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0px,-10000px,0)'; 
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(function() {
        t.style.webkitTransform = ''; 
    });
}

document.body.addEventListener('focus', stopScroll);
document.body.addEventListener('focusin', stopScroll);
```